# Databricks, What is the default location when using "writeStream"?

Tags: location, streaming, databricks

Assume that I want to write a table by `writeStream`. Where is the default location on DBFS where the table is saved?

Sample code:

```
spark.table("TEMP_SILVER").writeStream

    .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs:/user/AAA@gmail.com")

    .trigger(availableNow=True)

    .table("silver")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify just *silver* in `table` method, then you should look for you table in following location:

```
dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/silver
```

Comment: Thanks. If I set current database to "my_db", I guess the location should be "dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/my_db/silver". Is it correct?

Comment: That is correct.